# SSRS Model query - how to pass in a parameter?

Tags: reporting-services, model, ssrs-2008

I have a report based on Report Model and for creating dataset I use the query designer (as there is no real other way). However I am struggling with how to pass a report parameter to the query to use it as a filter. Anything starting with @ is considered as a syntax error...

Is there a way?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is in the Filter definition to specify the property as a 'prompt'. This will eventually create a parameter for which you then can map the value from the report parameters.